# Can't pass a python list entry to a function

Tags: python, list, function, typeerror

Hi I am working on a python program. I am able to retrieve data from my class's functions but not able to send data to them.

```
    class someClass:
        someList = []
        def sendMessage(message):
            someList.append(message)

    messageSender = someClass()

    listToSend = [] #loaded elswhere 

    someClass.sendMessage(listToSend[1])
```

When I go ahead and run it I get this error:

```
     TypeError: sendMessage() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

If I just use `someClass.someList = listToSend` it works, but this is for a unit test for a larger program so I really need to get sendMessage to work. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: It does not even get to the separate class but locks up on the function call. And I used that doc to make it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all class methods you should make the first argument of the method `self` following by the other arguments:

```
class someClass:
    someList = []
    def sendMessage(self, message):
        someList.append(message)

messageSender = someClass()

listToSend = [] #loaded elswhere 

someClass.sendMessage(listToSend[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

you are forgetting the self parameter in your function declaration of sendMessage.
`sendMessage(message)` should instead be `sendMessage(self, message)`

class someClass:
        someList = []
        def sendMessage(self,message):
            someList.append(message)

```
messageSender = someClass()

listToSend = [] #loaded elswhere 

someClass.sendMessage(listToSend[1])
```

### why did it tell me that I passed in 2 arguments?

whenever you call a method of a class, for example:

```
dog.bark()
```

you are passing in self (which is the dog variable) into the
method, therefore the call internally is `dog.bark(self)`.

The rule is:
visible parameters in method call + 1 = visible parameters in method declaration